# Смена двух цветов Button относительно коэффициента

Tags: java, android

Есть одна кнопка. Залитая одним цветом. При изменении условного параметра например  от 0 до 100, кнопка заполняется слева на право другим цветом. Эффект как в прогресс баре.

Вопрос 1. Как залить двумя разными цветами одну кнопку? Не градиентом, а Solid color

Вопрос 2. Как управлять этими параметрами, если к примеру на входе 
`void UpdateButtonBackground (color1, color2, percent)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу предложить сделать

```
public class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {
int color1;
int color2;
int percent;
paint mPaint;

//Передпределить draw
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint.setColor(color1);
        //параметры для drawRect соответственно вычисляем из длинны и percent
        canvas.drawRect();
        mPaint.setColor(color2);
        canvas.drawRect();
    }
}
```

Ну а этот drawable Уже вешать на кнопку.

Comment: Не знаю как прицепить drawable к кнопке, но я поищу и попробую, спасибо большое.

Comment: да так же как любое изображение setBackground или setBackgroundDrawable. С drawable удобно работать, они легко к любому view цепляются и можно отрисовку как хочешь менять.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Теперь знаю хотя бы в каком направлении смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Так может тогда все же лучше использовать обычный ProgressBar вместо кнопки и повесить на него событие onClick?

А цвет менять как обычно:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: К сожалению. Нужно это реализовать именно в бэкграунде кнопки...

Comment: Вынесите обработчик в отдельную функцию, поставьте две кнопки рядом с разным бэкграундом вместо одной. Меняйте их ширину и X координату правой при нажатии относительно друг-друга.